# Переадресация с одной страницы на другую

Tags: javascript, php, docker

Есть главная страница сайта, на ней 2 кнопки, хочу по нажатию на кнопку отправить POST-запрос на redirect.php и уже в нем определить, куда перенаправить. В POST-запросе в тело добавляю поле res, в котором записываю строку, от значения этой строки зависит, куда redirect.php должен перенаправить. Пытаюсь с помощью $_POST поймать поле res, затем в if сверяю возможные его значения, после этого переадресую с помощью header. header перенаправляет на файл addTask.php. В нем с помощью require вызываю страницы html. Запрос работает корректно, но вместо переадресации на другую страницу, в ответе приходят первые слова из той страницы, на которую, хочу переадресовать.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, может, как-то по-другому надо все это делать.

файл index.php

```
<?php
require('header.html');
require('main.html');
?>
```

файл redirect.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['res'] == 'addTask') {
    header('Location: addTask.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

файл addTask.php

```
<?php 
require('addTask.html');
?>
```

Запрос делаю так

```
addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('addTask button clicked');
    let arr = {
        res: 'addTask'
    };
    let params = new FormData();
    params.set('res', 'addTask')
    postData('index.php', params).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

Сама функция postData

```
//// Определяем функцию которая принимает в качестве параметров url и данные которые необходимо обработать
const postData = async (url = '', data = '') => {
    // Формируем запрос
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    }).then(response => response.json())
}
```

Все работает на Docker

Comment: Ajax запрос отправляете.. О какой переадресации речь? Если хотите переадресацию то или перепишите без ajax или возвращайте страницу куда переадресацию сделать надо, что-то типа этого: `if ($_POST['res'] == 'addTask') { return json_encode(['redirect_url' => '/addTask.php']); exit(); }` и обрабатывать `postData('index.php', params).then((data) => { window.location.href = data.redirect_url; })`

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Буду пытаться

Answer (score 0):

На основании InDevX переделал так

Запрос делается так

```
addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('addTask button clicked');
    let arr = {
        res: 'addTask'
    };
    let params = new FormData();
    params.set('res', 'addTask')
    postData('redirect.php', params).then((data) => {
        window.location.href = data.redirectURL;
    })
})
```

функция postData

```
//// Определяем функцию которая принимает в качестве параметров url и данные которые необходимо обработать
const postData = async (url = '', data = '') => {
    // Формируем запрос
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
    return await response.json();
}
```

файл redirect.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['res'] == 'addTask') {
    echo json_encode(['redirectURL' => 'addTask.php']);
}
?>
```